# "There was nothing to edit" since there was a lot of text

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just got a ban after only one mistake. I saw the post with a lot of text, and dirty links. I just wanted to review it by EDIT and simply replace dirty links with nice ones. But once I tap EDIT, I got an error:

`Stop!. Look and listen. There was nothing to edit.`

And then I see example of post I should reject, because it was empty but I started editing. Am I stupid or blind, that I cannot see that there was nothing? No. This way I got a ban exactly third time. So far it happened to mi three times. First two times, I reaaly was thinking, that it was because of me. But not now.

Did it happened to you also?

This is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9830581) to audit on the image below.

It is really annoying. It didn't because I was not paying attention. I have written complain to moderator. Can they bring my privileges to review back?

[image]

Comment: It was probably spam (and has since been deleted, which is why you don't see it now). Editing spam is counter-productive, and making their spam look better by formatting it is going against the interests of the site.

Comment: If you link to the actual audit, rather than provide a screenshot, you may have a helpful 10k user come along and tell you why the answer was deleted.

Comment: You wouldn't be automatically banned for one failure, and if you were manually banned by a moderator you'd get a message explaining why.

Comment: @TZHX i added a link to audit.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, after my previous ban disappear, I got another one, just after ONE mistake, described in question. Before I made mistake, I passed one test.

Comment: So, the second review after you started reviewing again was an audit that you failed?

Comment: @Cerbrus No, I made exactly 42 - 43 reviews. One of them was a test I passed. First 40 was "votes cast". The last one was I failed.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the review:

[image]

The post in there was spam, that's why "Edit" was the incorrect choice.

I have no idea how you did not see the contents of the post, maybe something is messing up the visibility of the post since it's deleted and you don't have the rep to see deleted posts.

Any way, if you open a review and you see "nothing", skip the review.
Or at very least, don't edit. I can't imagine what you were hoping to achieve editing an post that appeared to be empty.

Comment: I know, but it was not empty while I was reviewing it. And why I was banned just after one mistake? Was it critical mistake, or sth like that?

Comment: It's not a glitch; it's a known issue, and it always happens. Deleted posts used as audits are not shown to reviewers under 10k (/2k) after they pass or fail, although [there's a feature request to change that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228955/allow-all-reviewers-to-see-deleted-posts-they-reviewed).

Comment: If you've been review-banned before, it takes less failed audits to get banned again.

Comment: Yes, but I was banned before for 4 mistakes. Why now is only one?

Comment: Like I said, because you've been banned before. You get less room to make mistakes.

Comment: And every time you get banned, the ban lasts longer. @Bart